# Can I delete a file on the Desktop from a sandboxed Mac app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, nsfilemanager

I can get my Mac app to read the contents of the Desktop, but whenever I try and delete a file it says I don't have permission to do so. If the user has authorized access to the Desktop, shouldn't I be able to delete a file?

- Sandbox is turned on
- File access is set to read/write for User Selected File.
- The security scoped bookmarks are working because I have read access to the files, and it only comes up with the authorize prompt once.

This is the code I am using to delete:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation
                                                     source:desktopPath
                                                destination:@""
                                                      files:self.filesToDelete
                                                        tag:nil];
```

I also tried using the fileManager trash method with no success.

Here is the error that returns from the fileManager trash method:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“file.png” couldn’t be moved to the trash because you don’t have permission to access it." UserInfo=0x60000026a980 {NSURL=file:///Users/me/Desktop/file.png, NSUserStringVariant=(
Trash
), NSUnderlyingError=0x600000257ca0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -5000.)"}
```

And the actual trash method call:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] trashItemAtURL:url resultingItemURL:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: yes, when the user granted you the rights AND the USER can do it manually, then so should your app (AFAIK)

Comment: that is what I thought, so why am I getting that error? If I can read the files, shouldn't I be able to delete them? See above for the error

Comment: no if you can read them that doesn't mean you can delete them. that error indicates no sandbox error though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the user has selected the file through an open dialog, or you saved the file through your app using a save dialog, you won't be able to delete it in a sandboxed app.

There are a few directories where you can do what you want, mostly /tmp and the directories in your sandbox container.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned, the user does select Desktop with an open dialog. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to read the contents of the desktop, right? Without having them select the Desktop, the enumerator returns no files. After they select Desktop, I can read the desktop, I just can't delete.

Comment: Yes, and I'm telling you that unless they selected that *specific file*, you won't be able to delete it.  You can also delete files that you've created

Comment: @JonGilkison How then does [DaisyDisk](https://itunes.apple.com/app/daisydisk/id411643860?l=en&mt=12) work? You only drop your whole disk or individual folders onto its window and it’s able to delete everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - I've run into the same issue. I'm trying to use `trashItemAtURL` to trash a specific application in my `/Applications` folder in a Sandboxed App. However, even if I display a `NSOpenPanel` and get the user to specifically pick the Application I want to send to trash (with the help of `[panel setTreatsFilePackagesAsDirectories:YES];`), I still get a permission error. It seems even if you have write access to a folder/bundle in the `/Applications` folder, you still can't send it to trash.